# How to use Oracle documentation for constructing URI

Tags: java, dynamic-class-loaders

I went through `URL API` on Oracle documentation. I want to construct `URI` to refer `Jars` located on remote machine but, from the specs I am not able to make out how to use them. The document gives reference to `RFC2396` for specs. but, that too doesn't provide any concrete examples for its usage.

Comment: @Dave The link provided by you refers to parsing String in C/C++ languages.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you trying to use remote class loading (downloading a jar from a Web server or similar and then using it in a running program)?

Comment: Look at this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247716/remote-jars-in-the-classpath

Comment: @chrylis I want to load classes from the jar located on remote machine.

Comment: @Dave the link helps in answering my question thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code is useful for jar loading

```
Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), new Object[]{new URL("http://somewhere.net/library.jar")});  
Class.forName("your.remote.ClassName");
```