# how to use remote jars in classpath for javax.tools.JavaCompiler

Tags: java, java-compiler-api, javacompiler, jsr199

I'm using `JavaCompiler` to compile .java code.

It works for me while running the class compiled using `URLClassLoader` to load remote jars.
But not work while compiling.

Tried to use options like

```
options.addAll(Arrays.asList("-classpath", "https://example.com/example.jar"));
```

Also tried to use customized `JavaFileManager` with `URLClassLoader`.

None of them works.

Comment: sorry but i mean jar from network not local files

Comment: I think you have only two options :
1. JNLP (Java Network Launch Protocol) files
2. download jar in local files, set classpath then execute it manually with your program

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remote jars in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14247716/remote-jars-in-the-classpath)

Answer (score 0):

try below commands, and replace the .jar file with your external .jar file... into the command prompt or terminal.

`$ javac -cp ".:./jars/common.jar" helloworld.java 
$ java -cp ".:./jars/common.jar" helloworld`

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395207/how-to-include-jar-files-with-java-file-and-compile-in-command-prompt