# change library dependency from jar files into gradle dependencies

Tags: java, gradle

I want to stop using the local .jar library files I'm using in the Java files and want to import them by the online repository with gradle dependency.

I do the import but for some reason, the Java files do not recognize the library and can't compile my code after it.

for example:
library "flexjson" was in my local on the jar file.
and now changed the Gradle dependency to import it.

[image]

but for some reason my java stop recognize the library after I removed the jar lib in my local.

[image]

Comment: while it is generally possible, this is not  how (standard) java compilers work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14247716/592355 (they *all* (+build tools)  need (cache) local files) ;(

Comment: @xerx593 Both Gradle and Maven encapsulate their local caches of dependencies, so the developer doesn't usually need to worry about that.

Comment: I'm assuming you ran the build using Gradle, right? Not just a `javac` command.

Comment: But i think, developer: "...removed the jar lib in my local.", @E-Riz (and now expects his IDE to compile)

Comment: Yes, I build using gradle.  I thought that I can use them as imports when I add them as dependency to gradle

Comment: What IDE are you using? Is it aware of the Gradle dependencies?